# Stop a javascript function inside a jquery?

Tags: jquery

I want to cancel/stop a javascript function if some criteria is not matching in jquery

```
<div id="prewrapper">
    <ul class="tabs seller">
        <li class="active">
            <a onclick="adc.FormHandler.goto('user_edit', 0); return false;" href="#"><i data="1" class="icon-tab-num"></i> General Info</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a onclick="adc.FormHandler.goto('user_edit', 1); return false;" href="#"><i data="2" class="icon-tab-num"></i> Account Details</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a onclick="adc.FormHandler.goto('user_edit', 2); return false;" href="#"><i data="3" class="icon-tab-num"></i> Roles</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I check some validation in `$('#prewrapper').click(function (e){`, and if not valid I don't want to go href onclick function i.e., `adc.FormHandler.goto`

Comment: See: http://catcode.com/domcontent/events/capture.html

Comment: You know there's no such thing as a "jQuery Function," right?

Answer (score 0):

You're too late by that point, considering the event model in many browsers. Typically, events bubble from the "deepest" element up to the "shallowest" element.

You can fix that by delegating events with jQuery:

```
$('#prewrapper').on('click', 'a', function()
{
    if(someCondition)
       adc.FormHandler.goto('user_edit', $(this).data('edit-num');
});
```

Your `someCondition` tells us whether or not to invoke what used to be the click event on the actual element. You then mark your links with an attribute to store the user parameter:

```
<a data-edit-num="1" href="#">
```

Comment: The thing is that full form is created by a form handler method and methods are dynamically bind at that time..then now i am going to check some validations and if not i don't want to fire that already created event for an href ie,adc.FormHandler.goto..